# Publishing geospatial data with Plone

Tags: python, postgresql, plone, postgis, web-feature-service

I am setting up a new site on plone using collective.geo.bundle, but I need to make the data accessible to desktop GIS.  Two obvious ways of doing this are to use a postgres/postgis database, or to publish the data through a WFS service.  The problem is it appears that plone stores pickles in the database, so a GIS wouldn't be able to make sense of the data, and there doesn't seem to be an addon which exposes a WFS.  Two questions then:

1. Is there a way to use configure plone to use a postgres/postgis database with geometry data types, so that the data can be read from outside plone?
2. Is there a way to set up plone (e.g. through an addon) to expose a WFS?

Comment: Is your intention that the geospatial data can also be *edited* through Plone (namely `collective.geo.*` + OpenLayers), or just displayed by Plone? Because if not, defining an OpenLayers layer that consumes a centralized WMS service (instead of WFS) and configuring that layer for `collective.geo.*` should be enough.

Comment: Also: Could you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "configure Plone to use a postgis DB" - Plone itself doesn't do anything with geospatial data - it would be one of the `collective.geo.*` packages. But what exactly do you want to do with the data in Plone? Initially create it by georeferencing content types when adding them? Edit it in a mapwidget?

Comment: @LukasGraf I am using collective.geo.* to edit and view geospatial data, but the data created also needs to be accessible for analysis through a desktop GIS (read-only).  I've read up how to connect plone to a relational database, but the docs say that it stores pickle objects in the database, not actual values (in this case `geometry`) so I can only read the data from withing Plone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution (using `collective.geo.*`) that already does this.

As mentioned in the comments, Plone itself doesn't deal with geospatial data at all, it's `collective.geo.geographer` that does this. More specifically, it's the [`GeoreferencingAnnotator`](https://github.com/collective/collective.geo.geographer/blob/master/src/collective/geo/geographer/geo.py) that saves coordinates for `IGeoreferenceable` objects into their annotations (and loads them from there).

So, just forcing Plone to store its content in a relational DB, for example using `RelStorage` wont help you - Plone or RelStorage don't know about geospatial data, and will store those annotations like any other.

However, it shouldn't be *too* hard to write your own `IWriteGeoreferenced` adapter that writes the georeferencing data to a PostGIS database instead of annotations, using the [UUID](http://developer.plone.org/content/uid.html) of the context to link the data to the objects, and maybe store some additional metadata like Title or URL. This georeferencing data could completely separate from your actual content - there's no need to put all the Plone content into a PostgreSQL DB.

A different approach could be to write an event handler for the [`ObjectGeoreferencedEvent`](https://github.com/collective/collective.geo.geographer/blob/master/src/collective/geo/geographer/event.py#L13), and publish the georeferencing data to a PostGIS DB (in addition to having it stored in annotations on the actual objects). Since you only want to access it read-only from a desktop GIS, you wouldn't have to worry about syncing that data in both directions.

Last but not least, I would strongly suggest to have a look at the [`collective.geo` mailing list](http://www.coactivate.org/projects/collectivegeo/lists/collectivegeo-discussion) - people on there are usually very responsive and helpful, and I could well imagine someone else already had the same use case.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up.  I'm hoping to avoid writing my own tools for this, but if I do need to this gives me a good staring point!

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago, I developed zgeo.wfs https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zgeo.wfs to expose geo-referenced Plone contents through WFS.
It used to work on Plone 3 and it probably does not work anymore on Plone 4, nevertheless it could be a good starting point for you.

Note: I do not maintain it anymore as I prefer to use GeoJSON now.

Comment: I had a look at zgeo.wfs, but as you say it doesn't look maintained.  I'm curious about using geoJSON though.  I though it was just a JSON convention to represent spatial data, but if it can replace WFS does that mean it is actually a type of service which a GIS could connect to?  That might answer my problems!

Comment: You can use a GeoJSON layer pretty much like a WFS layer: you can display it in a web client (like OpenLayers or Leaflet), you can display it in GIS desktop client (like QGis). Pros: it is much easier to produce and to interpret. Cons: there is no standard way to query it. If operability is more important than interoperability to you, then GeoJSON is a good choice.

Comment: Its the "no standard way" that worries me slightly.  It will need to be accessed by QGIS and ArcGIS, and while QGIS shouldn't be a problem, I'm not so sure about ArcGIS.  I think I need to do some research.